# dll in pytorch failed

Tags: python, windows-10, pytorch

I'm using Windows 10 and pytorch 1 I've used pytorch successfully, however, after I loaded matplotlib the following error occurred: 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. for torch._C. 
This error  persist even though I have uninstall first matplotlib, then pytorch and re-installed pytorch. I have even created a new environment and installed pytorch into it. None of the posts I have seen helped me resolve the problem. It would appear that something has happened to the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

This issue is closed.  Simply update python to the most recent build will do.

```
conda update python
```

[Link to python issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10640)

The cause seems to be the recent python builds from default channel, either python 3.6.8 or 3.7.2.

[Link to the pytorch issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4518)

There are several ways to work around,

```
conda install python==3.7.1
```

or depends on which version you prefer

```
conda install python==3.6.7
```

or the most updated package python-3.7.2 build h8c8aaf0_6

```
conda install -c c3i_test python
```